# Count the number of elements with a specific class, then add an ID that numbers them

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dynamic, each

I'm very new to this, just trying to piece together snippets from other posts.

I'm unsure how to count the number of elements on a page, then add a class to differentiate them with a number.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').each(function (e) { $(this).addClass('count' + e); });
});
</script>

<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

output to:

```
<div class="item count1"></div>
<div class="item count2"></div>
<div class="item count3"></div>
```

Comment: What you have there should work (what you call "e" should be the index of the each loop, which should be exactly what you want); could you explain the problem you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('div.item').each(function(i,n){ $(n).addClass('count' + (i + 1));});
```

Comment: Marking it as an answer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.item').each(function (i, e) { $(e).addClass('count' + i); });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item').addClass(function(i){
    return "count" + (i + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is just fine if you just change:

```
$(this).addClass('count' + e);
```

to

```
$(this).addClass('count' + (e + 1));
```